# Writing Textures using Kernel

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

In single pass (In a single draw cycle) to the shader How many maximum Textures we can draw at once in metal using Kernel ? I have tried to draw six squared textures in a draw cycle.When the textures points overlap actual texture is not presented as expected. Some glitches are available